# How to show the by "which" command found path as a tree of symlinks to the actual executable?

Tags: linux, shell

I am not very familiar with all of the shell scripting features so if I want to list the entire link chain path to the actual executable for a command I am currently manually typing line by line:

```
~ $ which rename
/usr/bin/rename
~ $ file /usr/bin/rename
/usr/bin/rename: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/rename
~ $ file /etc/alternatives/rename
/etc/alternatives/rename: symbolic link to /usr/bin/file-rename
~ $ file /usr/bin/file-rename
/usr/bin/file-rename: Perl script text executable
```

What I would like to use instead of this multiple copy/paste work is one command named for example:

```
~ $ whichf rename
```

providing following output:

```
rename
 -> symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/rename
   -> symbolic link to /usr/bin/file-rename 
     -> Perl script text executable
```

Has someone already written such a command and can share it here so that don't need to reinvent the wheel?

---

I had already came up with following code:

```
~ $ s0=$s;echo $s0; s1=$(which rename);echo "  -> $s1";s2=$(file $s1); echo "    -> ${s2##*:}"
```

getting:

```
rename
  -> /usr/bin/rename
    ->  symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/rename
```

but this gives me only the first two lines of the entire path.

Comment: IMHO, the manual way of creating s0/s1/s2 and iterating over them is not logical. Instead, I think you should evaluate if it is a symbolic link or if it is an executable itself, and accordingly iterate deeper or quit.

Comment: OK, I'm not on my system, but maybe something like this helps:
`str=your_command
while : ; do
  ...
  echo $(which str);
  if [[ -L "$str" ]]; then 
      str=$(which str);
  else
      break
  fi
done`

Answer (score 0):

Using `readlink`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

whichf(){
    local prefix="  -> " c=$(type -t $1 2>/dev/null) new
    [[ $c = @(alias|builtin|function|keyword) ]] && { echo "$1 is a $c"; return; }
    test -z "$c" && { echo "$1 : not found."; return; }
    c="$(type -p $1)"
    echo "$1"
    while true; do
        echo "$prefix$c"
        new="$(readlink "$c")"
        if  test -z "$new"; then
            echo "  $prefix$(file "$c" | grep -oP '.*: \K.*')"
            break
        fi
        c="$new" prefix="  $prefix"
    done
}

whichf rename
```

Comment: See my answer for code exploiting the ability of `type` to report shell builtin commands. Notice that which and type can give different results, so naming the function using `type` as `whichf` does not mirror what it actually does, because it behaves not as which command would.

Comment: Your original post is about symbolic links, that's why I didn't explore other possibilities.

Comment: Yeah ... very nice approach with readlink, but with the chosen logic of using it `whichf bla-bla-bla` responds with *two* empty rows instead of only one. Try it yourself to see what I am speaking about.

Answer (score -1):

The code below below uses `which` and `file` commands along with shell string operations and a loop able to go down the path of symlinks to the  actual executable providing the feature you ask for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
whichf ( ) {
    # Custom 'which' named 'whichf' able to go down the chain of links 
    # to the actual executable (by Claudio 2023-03-11):
    s0=$1
    sb='  '
    echo $s0
    s1=$(which $s0)
    echo "$sb-> $s1"
    if [ ! -e "$s1" ]
    then
       return
    fi
    while : 
    do
        s2=$(file $s1 2>/dev/null)
        s3=${s2##*:}
        sb="  $sb"
        echo "$sb-> $s3"
        s4=${s3##* }
        if [ ! -e "$s4" ]
        then
            return
        fi
        s1=$s4
    done
}
export whichf
whichf $1
```

Use it at your own risk and have fun to see how deep the chain of links goes for the command 'rename':

```
~ $ whichf rename
rename
  -> /usr/bin/rename
    ->  symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/rename
      ->  symbolic link to /usr/bin/file-rename
        ->  Perl script text executable
~ $
```

and find out with its help that starting 'gnome-terminal' executes a Python script:

```
~ $ whichf gnome-terminal
gnome-terminal
  -> /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
    ->  Python script, ASCII text executable
~ $
```

For the sake of completeness below code of a `typef` function inspired by the other answer, but improved exploiting the ability of `type` to output information about shell builtin commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
typef(){
    local command indent="  -> " fpFName symLinkTarget
    command=$1
    echo $command
    maybe_fpFName="$(type $command 2> /dev/null)" 
    fpFName="${maybe_fpFName#*/}"
    if test -z "$fpFName"; then
        echo "$indent$maybe_fpFName"
        return
    fi
    fpFName="/$fpFName"
    if [ ! -e "$fpFName" ]; then
        echo "$indent$maybe_fpFName"
        return
    fi
    while : ; do
        echo "$indent$fpFName"
        if [ ! -e "$fpFName" ]; then
            break
        fi
        indent="  $indent"
        symLinkTarget=$(readlink "$fpFName")
        if  test -z "$symLinkTarget"; then # symLinkTarget is empty
            echo "$indent$(file "$fpFName" | grep -oP '.*: \K.*')"
            break
        fi
        fpFName="$symLinkTarget" 
    done
}
export typef
typef $1
```

Use it if you want to know which commands are considered to be builtin commands:

```
~ $ typef echo
echo
  -> echo is a shell builtin
~ $ typef type
type
  -> type is a shell builtin
```

Please **NOTICE** that because of the different approaches `whichf` and `typef` can deliver different results. For example the command `echo` is reported by typef as an builtin and by whichf as /usr/bin/echo executable. Using `type -a echo` you can see that echo can be both, a builtin shell command and present eventually even twice (also as /bin/echo) in the search paths as an executable file.